# Parse string into integers using delimiter C++

Tags: c++, parsing, int, delimiter

I am trying to make a callrate calculater where the input will be done as following: hh:mm

After this i want to parse that string into two ints with only ':' as a delimiter. This solution i got here seems to only work with space, but I want the delimiter to be colons, and not space. Is there even a possible way to do this?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    istringstream is(input);
    int hours, minutes; 

    is >> hours>> minutes;

    cout << timmar << endl;
    cout << minuter << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the delimiter character into another variable.

```
char colon;

is >> hours >> colon >> minutes;
if (colon != ':') {
    cout << "Incorrect delimiter: " << colon << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Such an easy solution! Wow. Thank you :)

Comment: Of course, it doesn't really "work" for interesting inputs. For example, `01 : 02` should probably fail to compile. The issue can be fixed using a `colon` manipulator: `std::istream& colon(std::istream& in){ if (in.peek() != ':') in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); else in.ignore(); return in; }`. You'd use this manipulator like Barmar's `char` but it creates an error if the colon isn't immediately following the `hours`. However, it would still allow spaces in front of the `minutes`. So, you'd really use `if (hours >> colon >> std::noskipws >> minutes >> std::skipws) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of expecting a default delimiter I'd use a custom manipulator to specifically deal with the delimiter:

```
std::istream& colon(std::istream& in) {
    if (in.peek() != ':' || std::isspace(in.ignore().peek())) {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
// ...
int hours, minutes;
if (in >> hours >> colon >> minutes) {
    // process the input
}
```

Using this manipulator avoid spaces in the proximity of the colon being considered valid: the normal input operation start off with skipping space. Reading the delimiter simply into a variable would allow spaces in front of the delimiter and also allow any non-space character as a delimiter. Carrying on reading directly after delimiter would, again, allow spaces after the delimiter. Using the `colon` manipulator above turns both of these cases into an error. ... and, of course, you *always* need to check *after* reading and *before* using the results whether input was successful.

---

An entirely different approach to the same problem is to redefine the stream's notation of *whitespace*. The idea here is to take advantage of the stream's `std::locale` and to `imbue()` a `std::locale` which considers the desired separator, e.g., `:` as the only "whitespace". Below is a complete example demonstrating that idea. It uses a separate `std::istream` with a custom `std::locale` to avoid changing how `std::cin` works. However, it still uses `std::cin` stream buffer, i.e., it reads from the same source as `std::cin`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

struct myctype_base {
    std::ctype<char>::mask table[std::ctype<char>::table_size];
    myctype_base(unsigned char c) {
        table[c] |= std::ctype_base::space;
    }
};
struct myctype
    : private myctype_base
    , std::ctype<char> {
public:
    myctype(char delimiter)
        : myctype_base(delimiter)
        , std::ctype<char>(myctype_base::table) {
    }
};

int main() {
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new myctype(':'));
    std::istream in(std::cin.rdbuf());
    in.imbue(loc);

    int hours, minutes;
    if (in >> hours >> minutes) {
        std::cout << "read hours=" << hours << " minutes=" << minutes << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "failed to read input\n";
    }
}
```